# Hide application icon from dock, but keep icon in task switcher?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, application-icon

It's possible to show/hide the application's icon from both the Dock and the Task Switcher by setting the "Application is agent (UIElement)" property to YES/NO.

However, is it possible to have an application show in the Task Switcher (Cmd + Tab), but not appear in the Dock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that this is impossible, and that the dock and the app switcher are using the exact same list to decide what should appear in them.

The reason for my believing this is that there's actually a procedure for removing an app's icon from the Dock, while the target app is running, that has nothing to do with the LSUIElement key. (It consists, essentially, of renaming/moving the app bundle and then restarting the Dock.) Even doing that, though, the app doesn't appear in the switcher.

(You can find the full procedure on macosxhints.com, if you're interested.)